# Throttling requests to third-party APIs when using cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, hubspot

We're running our Node backend on Firebase Functions, and have to frequently hit a third-party API (HubSpot), which is rate-limited to 100 requests / 10 seconds.

We're making these requests to HubSpot from our cloud functions, and often find ourselves exceeding HubSpot's rate-limit during campaigns or other website usage spikes. Also, since they are all write requests to update data on HubSpot, these requests cannot be made out of order.

Is there a way to throttle our requests to HubSpot, so as to not exceed their rate limit? Open to suggestions that may not necessarily involve cloud functions, although that would be preferred.

Note: When I say "throttle", I mean that all requests to HubSpot need to go through. I'm trying to achieve something similar to what [Lodash's throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle) method does, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we usually do in this case is store the data into a database, and then pass it over to HubSpot in a tempered way (e.g. without exceeding their rate limit) using a cron that runs every minute. For every data item that we pass to HubSpot successfully, we mark it as "success" in the database.

Comment: Yep, pretty much what we ended up doing. We update the properties of our HubSpot contacts in our Firestore database first, and then update that on HubSpot using their "Batch API" by running a scheduled function.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions can not be rate limited.  It will always attempt to service requests and events as fast as they arrive. But you can use [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/) to create an task queue to spread out the load of some work over time using a [configured rate limit](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/configuring-queues#rate). A task queue can [target another HTTP function](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks).  This effectively makes your processing asynchronous, but is really the only mechanism that Google Cloud gives you to smooth out load.